# SVG images not displaying fully on webpage

Tags: html, svg

I have a website where images are loaded through `<img src="..." />`

One of these images is [RSM's logo](https://assets.clicksminuteper.net/bots/rsm/normal.svg), however on the webpage it displays as this:

```html
<img src="https://assets.clicksminuteper.net/bots/rsm/normal.svg" />
```

This happens for almost all SVGs on the page, except for simple, single path shapes.

What causes this, and what ways can I fix it?

Update: This bug only appears to happen on chromium based browsers. Those show 2 of the grey bars and not the third, as well as not rendering the background.

Comment: Edited with code snippet

Comment: Its shows 2 of the grey bars and not the third, as well as not rendering the background

Comment: There are 3 grey bars when I run the Stack Snippet, and the background is a kind of pink colour. Is that not what it's supposed to look like? If not then we still need a [mcve]

Comment: I asked a friend on Discord, and it seems like its only happening on chromium, I assume you're on firefox or something similar

Comment: @RobertLongson I've tried running it on firefox & chromium, on firefox it renders fine but on chromium it seems to render with only 2 bars as OP suggests; perhaps it's an issue with embedded SVGs on chromium?

Comment: I've edited the question, any idea what fixes I could try?

Comment: Report Chrome bugs to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: On further inspection, it appears every url that works is ...net/web, and every broken url is something that isn't /web

Comment: Why would that make it display differently on Firefox compared to Chrome?

Comment: Not using the colon (:) for the id seams solving the problem. So try #paint0_linear_219_2 instead of #paint0_linear_219:2